# Medium-/long-term housing in Warsaw

Tags: eu-citizens, working, paperwork, housing, poland

I've been offered a job in Poland (Warsaw) and I have some questions before I accept it.

1. I've been offered roughly 4,000 PLN per month + health insurance. Is this enough to have a confortable life in Warsaw (I'll be living alone in the first months)?
2. In terms of housing, how does it work in Poland and what are the best websites to:

   2.1. Inform myself better about the local law.

   2.2. Flat rental listing websites.

   2.3. What are the best zones in Warsaw in terms of quality/price? I don't mind living in the suburbs and doing a daily commute, considering that I would be working in the city center.

Notes:

- I don't know if it makes a difference or not, but I'm an EU citizen
  (Portuguese).
- If I accept, it would initially be for a two-year contract.

Comment: Hi, you should definitely split the question into multiple parts

Comment: No i shouldn't. The question is well structured and in plain language. Over moderation is killing Stack websites... i didn't get a single reply, but got four times over moderators wanting to change everything. I do not want the question to be edited. If you guys still think it's wrong then just delete it. Thank you.